# User model with static set of related models

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have a `User` model in django and I want to add some achievements to users. So I've created an `Achieve` model:

```
class Achive:
    type = ....
    value = ....
    status = BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want all those achieves be a static set of models for every user (20 instances, for example) with ability to delete old and create new achieves. The problem is how to do it. Expected flow is:

1) user granted to use achievement system;

2) user got all those achieves (in admin panel shows like a table);

3) in admin panel per user I can change status of every achieve (affects only on edited user);

4) if new Achieve instance is created — add to all users who have achievements;

5) if existed Achieve instance has been deleted — remove from all users;

Solutions with I came up:

1) use Achieve model with jsonfield. store achieves in json like dictionary, use custom widget for admin panel to show checkboxes to change status). But where to store global set of achievements to create new/delete old ones? how to manage it?

2) use many to many field to Achieve and Achieve model without status. Why: if relation between User ← → Achieve exists, that means that user earn an achieve.

Both solutions I don't really like so hope for your advice.

P.S. sqlite is used as db and not allowed to use another (like mongo, etc.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at ManyToMany relationships through an intermediate model. So you have a set of achievements and the link to each User is an AchievementSatus which allows you to store extra information about that relationship, eg the status, the date the status was reached by this user, etc... see the [Django example with User, Group and Membership](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) as the `through` intermediate model.

Comment: @dirkgroten I think it solves my problem. Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a ManyToMany relationship between `Achieve` and `User`, but with the ability to store extra data on the relationship (the `status` for example).

With a normal `ManyToManyField` on a Model, Django actually creates an intermediate model to store the relationships in the database. By adding a `through` argument to your `ManyToManyField`, you can specify the intermediate model used for the relationship and store extra data with the relationship, as [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

```
class Goal(models.Model):
    type = ...
    value = ...
    achievers = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, through='Achievement', related_name='goals')

class Achievement(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField()
    date_reached = models.DateField(null=True)
    goal = models.ForeignKey(to=Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    achiever = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then you can create and query the relationships like this, assuming you have a `user` and a `goal`:

```
achievement = Achievement.objects.create(status=True, date_reached=date(2018, 10, 12), achiever=user, goal=goal)
user.goals.filter(achievement__status=True)  # gives the achieved goals of a user
goal.achievers.filter(achievement__status=True)  # gives the users that achieved a goal
```